# How to add auto increment column to csv Storage Engine type mysql table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a MySQL table which stored in CSV storage engine.
I want to create an auto increment column.But it isn't support for csv table.

Is there any way to create auto increment column using triggers?

Comment: What reason do you have by using CSV engine?

Comment: I have to use file watcher and to read the inserted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV storage engine also does not support indexes, so it would cause incredibly bad performance if you wanted to write a trigger to calculate the next id by `SELECT MAX(id)+1...` because every row insert would cause a table-scan.

If you need an auto-increment column, you must convert the table to InnoDB while adding the auto-increment column.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
  ADD COLUMN id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST, 
  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```